# Parsing youtube rss feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rss, reader

is there any fast and clean sample of reading these media keys like   in ruby?

Already I am using ruby rss and I am reading title,link but these media keys with semicolon I cant read. Should I use here nokogiri and xml key read? or standard ruby rss library has something for this keys?

Code I am using for reading youtube channel feed:

```
require 'rss'

rss = RSS::Parser.parse( "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA", false)

rss.items.take(2).reverse.each do |item|
puts item.title.content
end
```

And here is youtube response:

```
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"/>
<id>yt:channel:UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</id>
<yt:channelId>UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</yt:channelId>
<title>FES TV</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"/>
<author>
<name>FES TV</name>
<uri>
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA
</uri>
</author>
<published>2017-07-11T18:35:49+00:00</published>
<entry>
<id>yt:video:bXrwymDw4_Q</id>
<yt:videoId>bXrwymDw4_Q</yt:videoId>
<yt:channelId>UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</yt:channelId>
<title>...</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXrwymDw4_Q"/>
<author>...</author>
<published>2019-09-13T18:00:00+00:00</published>
<updated>2019-09-15T23:51:10+00:00</updated>
<media:group>
<media:title>
ONI NE ŽELE DA OVO ZNATE | Nemoguće slučajnosti i skrivena znanja
</media:title>
<media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/bXrwymDw4_Q?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
<media:thumbnail url="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bXrwymDw4_Q/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
<media:description>
Sećam se bilo je to davno kada sam pogledao dokumentarac pod nazivom Tajna ili Secret. Na kraju bio sam zatečen. Doboko u sebi osećao sam da u tome ima smisla. I ako sam tada znao mnogo manje nego što danas znam , počeo da primenjujem moć pozitivnih misli i da dajem sve od sebe da suzbijam negativne što više mogu. Želeo sam dve stvari i govorio u sebi " Bože neka se desi sve što mora samo ne daj da skrenem sa puta umetnosti i da budem sa ženom koja me ne voli." Ljubav je došla ali se činilo da mi umetnost okreće ledja. Pod utiskom Tajne , verovao sam . Usledio je poziv za moj budući bend. A sada znam da je samo taj poziv mogao da me zadrži da ponovo ne odem u Italiju i tamo ostanem da živim pogrešan život. Tada sam shvatio da moja ogromna želja izaziva buduće dogadjaje... Najveće tajne kriju se na najočiglednijim mestima.Pred očima i dušom. Istraživajući shvatio sam da je čuveni analitički psiholog Karl Jung posvetio skoro 30 godina istraživanju povezanosti misli i budućnosti. Zaključak nazvao je sinhronicitet. Ko želi da pomogne radu FES TV kanala može to uciniti uplatom na moj - 1 - PayPal preko ovog linka - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel 2 - Telenor Banka na racun 115-0381628762378-88 Mnogo hvala svakome ko to uradi ! Who wants to help me on the way to the truth can donate through this PayPal link - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel Thank you very much ! Zbog mnogo poruka , mejlova i komentara koje dobijam od vas nisam u mogucnosti da svakom odgovorim. Iz tog razloga ako imte neko važno pitanje da mi postavite , pišite mi na mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com Because of the many messages and comments I get from you, I'm not able to answer everyone. For this reason, if you have an important question to ask me, write me a mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com
</media:description>
<media:community>
<media:starRating count="2656" average="4.90" min="1" max="5"/>
<media:statistics views="58887"/>
</media:community>
</media:group>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: the code you have provided does not produce the same output you've shown.  did you leave something out?

Comment: no, look this is the xml from parsed url https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA this is preview of xml which is returned in parse

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated to handle your example XML

Rss feeds should return xml. As such, you can use the [ActiveSupport gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=def%20from_xml&unscoped_q=def%20from_xml) to parse it.

```
require 'rss'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'

rss = RSS::Parser.parse( "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA", false)

array = rss.entries.map do |e|
  Hash.from_xml(e.to_s)
end

# here is exactly what is contained in this array:
array.each{|i| puts i.inspect}
#returns
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:bXrwymDw4_Q", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXrwymDw4_Q", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-09-13T18:00:00+00:00", "title"=>"ONI NE ŽELE DA OVO ZNATE | Nemoguće slučajnosti i skrivena znanja", "updated"=>"2019-09-15T23:51:10+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:j4XZPSTv7Ng", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XZPSTv7Ng", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-09-05T18:01:10+00:00", "title"=>"RTANJ | Tajna najveće prirodne Piramide krije se u dubini !", "updated"=>"2019-09-10T05:37:24+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:pS1ciuLX_jQ", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS1ciuLX_jQ", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-08-28T18:00:38+00:00", "title"=>"Nestaje 30% Amazona-a | Istina koju niko ne govori", "updated"=>"2019-09-02T11:51:42+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:mvrdXJYRN3o", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvrdXJYRN3o", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-08-22T19:31:38+00:00", "title"=>"Magnetna letelica NIKOLE TESLE | Strogo čuvana tajna slobodne energije", "updated"=>"2019-08-25T01:24:21+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:uoJgcG2pG7U", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoJgcG2pG7U", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-08-16T18:00:07+00:00", "title"=>"OTKRIVENO ! Voda stara koliko i Zemlja ! U dubini leži ogromna količina vode..", "updated"=>"2019-08-21T06:23:51+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:OtB3nlfDTlg", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtB3nlfDTlg", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-26T18:00:16+00:00", "title"=>"IDENTIČNI | Video koji otvara Pandorinu kutiju", "updated"=>"2019-09-13T23:25:13+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:1WW3I6gpaI0", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WW3I6gpaI0", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-19T18:34:41+00:00", "title"=>"Strogo čuvana tajna | Video koji menja SVE", "updated"=>"2019-07-21T23:26:27+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:A3WYfyqUtCM", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3WYfyqUtCM", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-13T18:14:19+00:00", "title"=>"Dron snimio 2 UFO objekta iznad Hrvatske...NOVO !!", "updated"=>"2019-09-13T23:18:54+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:LLSfQOeYOXw", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLSfQOeYOXw", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-11T20:18:35+00:00", "title"=>"Edward Snowden - Video koji će vas dobro zamisliti !", "updated"=>"2019-09-16T02:04:09+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:pg21KbJGGQ8", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg21KbJGGQ8", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-06T18:02:18+00:00", "title"=>"Rover sa MARS-a poslao zbunjujuću SLIKU ?", "updated"=>"2019-09-10T05:17:19+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:sWXJCoakSGg", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWXJCoakSGg", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-07-04T18:00:40+00:00", "title"=>"Od MUNJE do 5G MREŽE | Video o misteriji tehnologije", "updated"=>"2019-09-15T23:46:36+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:CjQRz-QBN0M", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjQRz-QBN0M", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-06-29T17:02:11+00:00", "title"=>"Doktori koji su otkrili začudjujuće činjenice o mozgu !", "updated"=>"2019-09-01T10:39:17+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:4lRH5mlP55g", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lRH5mlP55g", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-06-21T18:45:25+00:00", "title"=>"Ukrajinski UFO slučaj...Istina se pokazala neočekivano...!", "updated"=>"2019-07-27T04:12:15+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:9Rbm6rf71DE", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Rbm6rf71DE", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-06-19T18:52:03+00:00", "title"=>"BIONI su šta ?... Ovo će vas dobro zamisliti ( neverovatan intervju ) ! Goran Mitić", "updated"=>"2019-08-25T01:12:55+00:00"}}
{"entry"=>{"author"=>{"name"=>"FES TV", "uri"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}, "id"=>"yt:video:X-CpIriD99M", "link"=>{"href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-CpIriD99M", "rel"=>"alternate"}, "published"=>"2019-06-17T19:40:42+00:00", "title"=>"UŽIVO -  Da pomogne brat bratu i sestra sestri", "updated"=>"2019-07-02T22:48:42+00:00"}}
```

The problem is that none of this contains the XML you pasted in you question so lets define it as you have it:

```
xml  = <<-XML
    <feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"/>
    <id>yt:channel:UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</id>
    <yt:channelId>UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</yt:channelId>
    <title>FES TV</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"/>
    <author>
    <name>FES TV</name>
    <uri>
    https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA
    </uri>
    </author>
    <published>2017-07-11T18:35:49+00:00</published>
    <entry>
    <id>yt:video:bXrwymDw4_Q</id>
    <yt:videoId>bXrwymDw4_Q</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA</yt:channelId>
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXrwymDw4_Q"/>
    <author>...</author>
    <published>2019-09-13T18:00:00+00:00</published>
    <updated>2019-09-15T23:51:10+00:00</updated>
    <media:group>
    <media:title>
    ONI NE ŽELE DA OVO ZNATE | Nemoguće slučajnosti i skrivena znanja
    </media:title>
    <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/bXrwymDw4_Q?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bXrwymDw4_Q/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
    <media:description>
    Sećam se bilo je to davno kada sam pogledao dokumentarac pod nazivom Tajna ili Secret. Na kraju bio sam zatečen. Doboko u sebi osećao sam da u tome ima smisla. I ako sam tada znao mnogo manje nego što danas znam , počeo da primenjujem moć pozitivnih misli i da dajem sve od sebe da suzbijam negativne što više mogu. Želeo sam dve stvari i govorio u sebi " Bože neka se desi sve što mora samo ne daj da skrenem sa puta umetnosti i da budem sa ženom koja me ne voli." Ljubav je došla ali se činilo da mi umetnost okreće ledja. Pod utiskom Tajne , verovao sam . Usledio je poziv za moj budući bend. A sada znam da je samo taj poziv mogao da me zadrži da ponovo ne odem u Italiju i tamo ostanem da živim pogrešan život. Tada sam shvatio da moja ogromna želja izaziva buduće dogadjaje... Najveće tajne kriju se na najočiglednijim mestima.Pred očima i dušom. Istraživajući shvatio sam da je čuveni analitički psiholog Karl Jung posvetio skoro 30 godina istraživanju povezanosti misli i budućnosti. Zaključak nazvao je sinhronicitet. Ko želi da pomogne radu FES TV kanala može to uciniti uplatom na moj - 1 - PayPal preko ovog linka - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel 2 - Telenor Banka na racun 115-0381628762378-88 Mnogo hvala svakome ko to uradi ! Who wants to help me on the way to the truth can donate through this PayPal link - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel Thank you very much ! Zbog mnogo poruka , mejlova i komentara koje dobijam od vas nisam u mogucnosti da svakom odgovorim. Iz tog razloga ako imte neko važno pitanje da mi postavite , pišite mi na mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com Because of the many messages and comments I get from you, I'm not able to answer everyone. For this reason, if you have an important question to ask me, write me a mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com
    </media:description>
    <media:community>
    <media:starRating count="2656" average="4.90" min="1" max="5"/>
    <media:statistics views="58887"/>
    </media:community>
    </media:group>
    </entry>
    </feed>
    XML
array = Hash.from_xml()
```

Use [nori gem](https://github.com/savonrb/nori)

First do `gem install nori` as it seems to handle name-spaced tags. Then in your code

```
require 'nori'

# now the easy nori magic
parser = Nori.new
hash = parser.parse(xml)
pp hash
=>{"feed"=>
  {"link"=>
    [{"@rel"=>"self",
      "@href"=>
       "http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"},
     {"@rel"=>"alternate",
      "@href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA"}],
   "id"=>"yt:channel:UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA",
   "yt:channelId"=>"UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA",
   "title"=>"FES TV",
   "author"=>
    {"name"=>"FES TV",
     "uri"=>
      "\n" + "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA\n"},
   "published"=>Tue, 11 Jul 2017 18:35:49 +0000,
   "entry"=>
    {"id"=>"yt:video:bXrwymDw4_Q",
     "yt:videoId"=>"bXrwymDw4_Q",
     "yt:channelId"=>"UCAUZpKBrZ-QP72Y0blet6DA",
     "title"=>"...",
     "link"=>
      {"@rel"=>"alternate",
       "@href"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXrwymDw4_Q"},
     "author"=>"...",
     "published"=>Fri, 13 Sep 2019 18:00:00 +0000,
     "updated"=>Sun, 15 Sep 2019 23:51:10 +0000,
     "media:group"=>
      {"media:title"=>
        "\n" +
        "ONI NE ŽELE DA OVO ZNATE | Nemoguće slučajnosti i skrivena znanja\n",
       "media:content"=>
        {"@url"=>"https://www.youtube.com/v/bXrwymDw4_Q?version=3",
         "@type"=>"application/x-shockwave-flash",
         "@width"=>"640",
         "@height"=>"390"},
       "media:thumbnail"=>
        {"@url"=>"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bXrwymDw4_Q/hqdefault.jpg",
         "@width"=>"480",
         "@height"=>"360"},
       "media:description"=>
        "\n" +
        "Sećam se bilo je to davno kada sam pogledao dokumentarac pod nazivom Tajna ili Secret. Na kraju bio sam zatečen. Doboko u sebi osećao sam da u tome ima smisla. I ako sam tada znao mnogo manje nego što danas znam , počeo da primenjujem moć pozitivnih misli i da dajem sve od sebe da suzbijam negativne što više mogu. Želeo sam dve stvari i govorio u sebi \" Bože neka se desi sve što mora samo ne daj da skrenem sa puta umetnosti i da budem sa ženom koja me ne voli.\" Ljubav je došla ali se činilo da mi umetnost okreće ledja. Pod utiskom Tajne , verovao sam . Usledio je poziv za moj budući bend. A sada znam da je samo taj poziv mogao da me zadrži da ponovo ne odem u Italiju i tamo ostanem da živim pogrešan život. Tada sam shvatio da moja ogromna želja izaziva buduće dogadjaje... Najveće tajne kriju se na najočiglednijim mestima.Pred očima i dušom. Istraživajući shvatio sam da je čuveni analitički psiholog Karl Jung posvetio skoro 30 godina istraživanju povezanosti misli i budućnosti. Zaključak nazvao je sinhronicitet. Ko želi da pomogne radu FES TV kanala može to uciniti uplatom na moj - 1 - PayPal preko ovog linka - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel 2 - Telenor Banka na racun 115-0381628762378-88 Mnogo hvala svakome ko to uradi ! Who wants to help me on the way to the truth can donate through this PayPal link - PayPal.Me/FESTVyoutubechannel Thank you very much ! Zbog mnogo poruka , mejlova i komentara koje dobijam od vas nisam u mogucnosti da svakom odgovorim. Iz tog razloga ako imte neko važno pitanje da mi postavite , pišite mi na mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com Because of the many messages and comments I get from you, I'm not able to answer everyone. For this reason, if you have an important question to ask me, write me a mail - pisitenafestv@gmail.com\n",
       "media:community"=>
        {"media:starRating"=>
          {"@count"=>"2656", "@average"=>"4.90", "@min"=>"1", "@max"=>"5"},
         "media:statistics"=>{"@views"=>"58887"}}}},
   "@xmlns:yt"=>"http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015",
   "@xmlns:media"=>"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/",
   "@xmlns"=>"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution but you will see i am still dont seeing this media:group  values https://ibb.co/5F5f8BZ in this specific case I need media:description   content somehow your solution is clean and it shows these roots keys above <media:group>

Comment: I'm not sure why but it seems that whatever your RSS is sending back doesn't match your example xml. I've updated to provide alternate example, but the hash methods also work on your sample XML